# Iterate into list in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, iteration

You will find below the input, the output and the output wanted :

Input :

```
Seasons = ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16']
SeasonType = ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']

myDict = {'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': Seasons, 'SeasonType': SeasonType}

for Sea in Seasons:
  for typ in SeasonType:
    print(myDict)
```

Output :

```
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16'], 'SeasonType': ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs']}
```

Output wanted :

```
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2013-14', 'SeasonType': 'Regular Season'}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2014-15', 'SeasonType': 'Regular Season'}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2015-16', 'SeasonType': 'Regular Season'}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2013-14', 'SeasonType': 'Playoffs'}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2014-15', 'SeasonType': 'Playoffs'}
{'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': '2015-16', 'SeasonType': 'Playoffs'}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for typ in SeasonType:
  myDict['SeasonType'] = typ
  for Sea in Seasons:
    myDict['Season'] = Sea
    print(myDict)
```

Comment: This is almost there - to get the exact output requested, the outer loop must be on `SeasonType`, and the inner on `Seasons`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to choose what to show, you can do it like this:

```
for Sea in Seasons:
  for typ in SeasonType:
     print({'LeagueID': '00', 'Season': Sea, 'SeasonType': typ}
```

Comment: Indeed it gives me the good output. But is there a way to use "myDict" whereas retyping the dictionnary ? Because the case I shown is simplified. I have something like 10 keys, and up to 4 lists in it. So I won't be able to print each ones.
Thank you!

Comment: not in a simple/smart way, if you want to print the dictionary but in a format different than the dictionary is, you are printing a different dictionary, so you'll have to create it